# Fit the height of the chapter number to n-times the height of the chapter name

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, scaling

I would to get the chapter number tall n-times the chapter name in order to have a better proportion between the two elements. Why I get errors and how can I fix that behaviour?

I thought something like this to include it:

```
\setbox4\hbox{\resizebox*{!}{\myheight}{\hspace{10pt}}}
\edef\hchapterspace{\the\wd4}
```

And use `\hchapterspace`

but I get: `Package graphics Error: Division by 0 }`

So the simplest way is:

```
...\hspace{10pt}\vline\hspace{10pt}}\ }{0pt}
```

but is the same thing to use `{10pt}` as `\titleformat` argument?

---

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbox10\hbox{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\spacedallcaps{\chaptername}}

\setbox20\hbox{\resizebox*{!}{\dimexpr\ht10*3\relax}{\chapterNumber\thechapter}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}%
        {{\color{halfgray}\box20%
        \hspace{10pt}\vline}  }{10pt}%
        {\spacedallcaps}

\begin{document}

\chapter{graphic test}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to load graphic[sx] package for resizebox. Also are you _sure_  it's safe to use box 20?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbox0\hbox{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\spacedallcaps{\chaptername}}
\edef\myheight{\the\dimexpr 3\ht0\relax}


\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}%
        {\color{halfgray}\resizebox*{!}{\myheight}{\chapterNumber\thechapter
        \hspace{10pt}\vline}}{10pt}%
        {\spacedallcaps}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{chapter}

\chapter{graphic test}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

It is only safe to use boxes 0 2 4 6 8 as local scratch registers and you need to use them *locally* you can not assume that if you set it at one place the box has a usable value later in the document. Also you did not want a box at all for the chapter number that boxed the text when the counter was at 0 and so using the box in the chapter heading would not give the chapter number even if box20 had been safe to use.

---

Comment on the updated question about horizontal spacing. If you add the space after the resizebox or (I suspect, equivalently) in the following argument of `\titleformat` then the space added will be the space specified. If on the other hand you add the space before the closing `}` of the `\resizebox` then the space will be scaled in proportion to the scaling of the number, so if the `\resizebox` ends up scaling by (say) 3.1 times then `\hspace{10pt}` will produce 31pt of white space in the output. The choice is entirely up to you which you feel a more natural specification.

Comment: With your code I get:  `Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: If I comment `\show\chapterNumber` the error go away...

Comment: oops:-) that isn't an error of course but your ide might think it is, yes it's just debugging I'll delete it from the answer

Comment: Is it also possible include this `{10pt}` space (after `\vline`) in the resize box?

Comment: That's an argument to titleformat isn't it?

Comment: I think so, check my updated question...

Comment: So, why if the `\hspace{10pt}` is put into a resize box in the titleformat command is resized and if it is put alone in the resize box isn't resized?

Comment: because a `\hbox{A\hspace{10pt}}` has height (the height of a A) so you can scale it to any size, scaling by a factor of desired size divided by height of A, but if you try that with `\hbox{\hspace{10pt}}` you need desired size divided by 0 which is not computable

Comment: Re-updated my question...